# WPF - Can I stop UserControl exposing its named child elements?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, encapsulation

This is a bit of a noob question but I've just realised that if i create a UserControl and choose to name some of its child elements a la -

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.uControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid x:Name="maingrid">

</Grid>
```

then i can reference the named elements in the code-behind of the consuming XAML.  So for the example above i could write

```
uControl.mainGrid = new Grid();
```

I'm curious as to why this is the case and more importantly, how i can safely encapsulate these controls.

As usual, ANY help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the [`x:FieldModifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970905.aspx) attribute:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.uControl" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Width="300" Height="300">
    <Grid x:Name="maingrid" x:FieldModifier="private">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The default is **internal**, for some reason.  You can read more about it [here](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/01/07/make-use-of-the-xfieldmodifier-attribute/).

Comment: lol.  That's the worst design decision I've seen yet!  Thanks man, big help.